# Entity Framework insert doesn't work

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, datagridview, ado.net

I have a very simple windows form project with Entity Framework.

Simply I draged my tables from "Data Source" tab in my "form" and it generate for me a "DataGridView" and a "BindingSource".

Data bound successfully and when I run project I can see "DataGridView" filled with data correctly and I can update any cells value from "DataGridView".

Problem is I can not insert any rows in my "DataGridView".

Here is some codes that I wrote hope it be useful to solve problem:

```
    Teachers_DBEntities context = new Teachers_DBEntities();

    private void SaveItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        context.SaveChanges();
        MessageBox.Show("saved successfully");
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        teachers_tableBindingSource.DataSource = context.teachers_table.ToList();
    }
```

**Upates for comments**

I tested my "BindingSource" and found that it successfully understand if new record insert in "DataGridVeiw", but changes won't apply in database when I call `context.savechanges();`

`context.savechanges()` works fine when I update a cell, but it doesn't work when I try to insert a new record in my "DataGridView".

In my edmx file I mapped all columns correctly and primary key `StoreGeneretedPattern` property is set to `Identity` and its `Entity Key` property is set to `true`. Its `auto-increment` property in my SQL Server database file is set to `true`.

any help is appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure the identity (pk) of the object isn't already in the database ?

Could you add the complete code with AddObject and so on?

Comment: Thank you Boas for reply. My (pk) is auto-increment and I don't enter any value for it. I tried to insert value in database with AddObject but problem is I don't know how to understand when adding new row in "DataGridView" is completed.

Comment: Is your table empty ? Did you already tried it with an empty table ?

Comment: And Can check for validation errors before savechanges?

Comment: Boas, I updated my question and I answered your questions in it.

Comment: Boas, i tried it with an empty table, same result. How can I check validation error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> context.savechanges() works fine when I update a cell, but it doesn't work when I try to insert a new record in my "DataGridView".

What do you mean by "it doesn't work"? New record does not appear in database? Of course it won't.

In this line

```
teachers_tableBindingSource.DataSource = context.teachers_table.ToList();
```

you're breaking `DataSource`'s connection to context. Any new item inserted into it will be inserted not into `teachers_table`, but into `List` you created over it.

Comment: Thank you, and what is solution? How can I fill my `DataGridView` when project starts up without breaking `DataSource`?

Comment: I have exactly the same problem as Masoud, buy I don't see solution here. I fully understand the issue cause (inserting in duplicate list instead of the originial one), but... what's the solution?

Answer (score 1):

```
using (var context = new YourEntities ()) 
{
     var dpt = new yourObject { Name = "Test" };
     context.yourObject.Add(dpt);
     context.SaveChanges(); 
}
```

you are missing to add object in the context

Comment: Thank you for reply. Is it possible to bind "DataGridView" to context? I mean whenever I insert new row in "DataGridView" context add new object automatically. If not then how can I understand when new row adding has completed in "DataGridView" to write code for it?

Answer (score 0):

In .Net 4.5 I get this error when I remove ToList():

> Data binding to a store query is not supported.

Instead populate a **DbSet** with data, for example by calling Load on the DbSet, and then bind to local data.

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly this same problem. And after a lot of hours, I just finally found myself the solution...

I'm using C#, .Net Framework, Entity Framework 6.4

If I set

```
teachers_tableBindingSource.DataSource = context.teachers_table.ToList();
```

data is updated in DB but not inserted.

If I set (as suggested)

```
teachers_tableBindingSource.DataSource = context.teachers_table;
```

I get the error:

> System.NotSupportedException   HResult=0x80131515   Mensaje = Data
> binding directly to a store query (DbSet, DbQuery, DbSqlQuery,
> DbRawSqlQuery) is not supported. Instead populate a DbSet with data,
> for example by calling Load on the DbSet, and then bind to local data.
> For WPF bind to DbSet.Local. For WinForms bind to
> DbSet.Local.ToBindingList(). For ASP.NET WebForms you can bind to the
> result of calling ToList() on the query or use Model Binding, for more
> information see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=389592.

Finally I got the answer tnanks to that hint:

```
context.teachers_table.Load(); //Load records in this DataSet<>

teachers_tableBindingSource.DataSource = context.teachers_table.Local.ToBindigngList();
```

Now it works. Data is deleted, inserted and updated properly in database.