# Entity Framework 4.0 insert/delete not working

Tags: c#, winforms, entity-framework, data-binding, datagridview

I have got a simple Windows Forms application using a DataGridView to display and edit data from the Northwind sample database. The data is accessed through EF.

While I have no issues updating rows in the database. I am unable to insert/delete data. All inserts/deletes are reflected in the `RegionBindingSource` but NOT in the entity `Context`.

I have read similar topics on that issue (like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11790575/entity-framework-insert-doesnt-work)). In most cases the binding is broken by .ToList(). Not here. It is not a database issue, I can easily edit the table using WPF databinding.

What am I missing?

```cs
public class NorthwindViewModel
{
    public BindingSource RegionBindingSource { get; private set; }

    public NorthwindEntities Context { get; private set; }

    public NorthwindViewModel()
    {
        Uri svcUri = new Uri("http://localhost:12345/Northwind.svc");
        Context = new NorthwindEntities(svcUri);
        RegionBindingSource = new BindingSource(Context, "Region");
        RegionBindingSource.AllowNew = true;

    public void SaveChanges()
    {
        Context.SaveChanges();
    }
}

public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private NorthwindViewModel viewModel;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        viewModel = new NorthwindViewModel();
        dataGridView1.DataSource = viewModel.RegionBindingSource;
    }

    private void save_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        viewModel.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

Comment: Not working means? Is it giving you some exception or it remain silent and do nothing?

Comment: I'm not getting an exception. `Context` is just not updating with the bindingsource.

Comment: What about to process BinDingSource.ListChanged event?

Comment: Thank you! I got it working by subscribing to the ListChanged event and doing things manually. But shouldn’t the binding handle inserts/deletes automatically?